# Given a video URL, how can I save a clip of the video onto the Android phone?

Tags: android, video, fileoutputstream, mediamuxer, mediaextractor

Given a video url (ex: www.example.com/video.mp4), how can I programatically save a short clip of the video (ex: 5 seconds, 00:00:10 - 00:00:15) in an Android application onto the phone?

At the moment, here is what I have - but this saves the entire video from the url to the device. It appears I'll need to use a MediaExtractor and MediaMuxer.

```
URL url = new URL(http_url_path);
URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

// Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
// uses 5KB download buffer
InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(is, BUFFER_SIZE);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
byte[] buff = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

int len = 0;
while ((len = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
    out.write(buff, 0, len);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rely on isoviewer-1.0-RC-27.

```
public static double[] startTrim(File src, File dst, int startMs, int endMs) throws IOException {
    Movie movie = MovieCreator.build(src.getAbsolutePath());
    List<Track> tracks = movie.getTracks();
    movie.setTracks(new LinkedList<Track>());
    double startTime = startMs/1000;
    double endTime = endMs/1000;
    boolean timeCorrected = false;
    // Here we try to find a track that has sync samples. Since we can only start decoding
    // at such a sample we SHOULD make sure that the start of the new fragment is exactly
    // such a frame
    for (Track track : tracks) {
        if (track.getSyncSamples() != null && track.getSyncSamples().length > 0) {
            if (timeCorrected) {          
                throw new RuntimeException("The startTime has already been corrected by another track with SyncSample. Not Supported.");
            }
            //false,Short interception;true,Long interception
            startTime = correctTimeToSyncSample(track, startTime, true);
            endTime = correctTimeToSyncSample(track, endTime, false);
            timeCorrected = true;
        }
    }
    int x = 0;
    for (Track track : tracks) {
        long currentSample = 0;
        double currentTime = 0;
        long startSample = -1;
        long endSample = -1;
        x++;
        for (int i = 0; i < track.getDecodingTimeEntries().size(); i++) {
            TimeToSampleBox.Entry entry = track.getDecodingTimeEntries().get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < entry.getCount(); j++) {
                // entry.getDelta() is the amount of time the current sample covers.
                if (currentTime <= startTime) {
                    // current sample is still before the new starttime
                    startSample = currentSample;
                }
                if (currentTime <= endTime) {
                    // current sample is after the new start time and still before the new endtime
                    endSample = currentSample;
                } else {
                    // current sample is after the end of the cropped video
                    break;
                }
                currentTime += (double) entry.getDelta() / (double) track.getTrackMetaData().getTimescale();
                currentSample++;
            }
        }
        movie.addTrack(new CroppedTrack(track, startSample, endSample));
        break;
    }
    Container container = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(movie);  
    if (!dst.exists()) {
        dst.createNewFile();
    }

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dst);
    FileChannel fc = fos.getChannel();
    container.writeContainer(fc);      
    fc.close();
    fos.close();
    double[] doubleArray = new double[2] ;
    doubleArray[0] = startTime;
    doubleArray[1] = endTime;
    return doubleArray;

}
```

Comment: Thank you @sundroid . Is there a reason to only use isoviewer-1.0-RC-27? I see a 1.0-RC-35 here: https://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/downloads/list?q=label:Type-Executable  . Also, I see isoviewer 1.0.5 here: https://github.com/sannies/isoviewer/releases  .   There is also mp4parser located here: https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser/releases . Which should I use?

Comment: You should use the one who provide implement for the function,you should read api.and isoviewer-1.0-RC-27 can serve it.

Comment: Thank you @sundroid I figured out that only isoparser-1.0-RC-27.jar would provide the correct APIs.

Comment: I had a question @sundroid . For some reason, I specify 10000 (start) and 20000 (end) , but the produced video clip is from 12.499999 to 17.499999  (only 5 seconds).   Why is it not using 10 second duration?

Comment: Check your settings and maybe the duration can be set up!

Comment: Hi @sundroid , here is the implementation for my correctTimeToSyncSample(). Does it look correct to you? http://pastebin.com/6L5qD7xd

Comment: Hi @sundroid , this code seems to save a clipped video correctly, but there is no idea. Do you know why?

Comment: Thank you so much @sundroid. Is it possible to capture a video clip from a URL (instead of local File). I'd like to avoid having to download the video from the server to the phone. Some videos are fairly large.

Answer (score 0):

:D  or easily you  can use  this website :D just send link you want  using  intent

http://www.videograbber.net/